# ffmpeg: command not found

Tags: ffmpeg

I have ffmpeg installed in my Ubuntu 14.04 (and also no ffmpeg for 16.04) but when I tried to use it in terminal I got the following error,

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.avs -an -vcodec rawvideo -y output.avi
ffmpeg: command not found
```

I check it in my /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin but I can't find it. I make sure to have it again by apt-get install, and it say ffmpeg is already the newest version.

How can I use ffmpeg in command window?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I successfully figured it out by my self, here is how.

1. remove the current ffmpeg by running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge ffmpeg
   ```
2. Add ppa trusty-media for 14.04:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
   ```

   For 16.04, add the following Repo:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-3
   ```
3. Update repo:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Finally install it:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
   ```

Comment: @andrew-46: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/699518/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Install the dependencies by typing [Link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu#ffmpeg):

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install autoconf automake build-essential libass-dev libfreetype6-dev \
libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev libtool libva-dev libvdpau-dev libvorbis-dev  libxcb1-dev libxcb-shm0-dev \
libxcb-xfixes0-dev pkg-config texinfo zlib1g-dev
```

**ffmpeg**

```
mkdir /home/user/ffmpeg
cd /home/user/ffmpeg
wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig"      ./configure \
--prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
--pkg-config-flags="--static" \
--extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
--extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
--bindir="$HOME/bin" \
--enable-gpl \
 ......
 .......
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make
make install
make distclean
```

Then execute:

```
home/user/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -i ../input.avs ../videos/output.avi
```